# How do I add "/home" to the site's url

Tags: php, wordpress, function

The site's actual url is "allenbrookneighbors.org".

In settings/reading "your homepage display" is set to "a static page" and "Homepage:" is set to "Home". There is no "/home" directory in the site's file structure. "Home.php" is just a blank static page; after wp's heirarchy search, front-page.php is loaded when a user comes to the site.

There is a small amount of dynamic content—a quote about "neighbors"—on the front page which is intended to change when the page is refreshed.
It works beautifully in firefox desktop but not in chrome, edge, safari, or even firefox mobile.

We discovered that we could bypass these browsers' local cache and get new dynamic data every time if the user appends "/home" to the site url: "allenbrookneighbors.org/home" and hits {enter}, but users don't know to do this.

We thought we could write a redirect function that would simply add the "/home" modifier to the incoming url, but the page doesn't load; we get a message saying, "The page isn’t redirecting properly. [Browser] has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_home_url');
function redirect_home_url() {
  if (is_front_page() && !isset($_GET['redirected'])) {
    wp_redirect(home_url('/home'));
    exit;
  }
}
```

So the question is: Is there a way that works to automatically add "/home" to the url in the address bar (if it is not already there) so users will see the new content if they come to the page more frequently than their browser's local cache expires?  Or also, so if a user presses the refresh button after reading the content, they will see new content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me the significance of `Home.php`. If you visit `<yoursite>/home`, it will not load that file (unless you have some funny htaccess/server config). Or did you mean Home.php static page in your WP template?

You're probably getting the infinite redirect because /home is still handled by WP and it doesn't know that you want to stop redirecting when /home is reached. Additionally, the `isset($_GET['redirected'])` won't work since that parameter is not being set (at least I can't see that here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/#source).

So I'm guessing that you'd need to at least use this instead:

```php
wp_redirect(home_url('/home?redirected=1'));
```

---

> How do I configure the server to "tell the browsers how long something should be cached..."

This depends a bit on the server, but in principle you just need to set response headers, which means that you can also do it in PHP (if you are using PHP to server resources).

#### Examples

- ```
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  ```

  If you put that in an `.htaccess`, all affected resources should be cached by anyone for one day (86400s => 24h, public => anyone). See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control
- ```
  <FilesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </FilesMatch>
  ```

  Same as before, but only for those specific file extensions.
- ```
  header('Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"');
  ```

  The PHP version. Could be useful for, for example, sitemap generators, dynamic assets etc.

#### Refreshing the cache

The HTTP standards is very flexible, it provides ways to cache, invalidate as well as avoid caching.

MDN provides some case scenarios as well as possibilities on busting the cache. See this for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#caching_static_assets_with_cache_busting

It's basically what I mentioned here: [How do I add "/home" to the site's url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77553524/how-do-i-add-home-to-the-sites-url/77553575?noredirect=1#comment136742476_77553575)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Adding "/home" to the base url in the browser address bar loads the homepage just as the plain home_url() does, but it bypasses the local browser caches in chrome, safari, and edge.  There's dynamic content on the homepage, but not enough, apparently to trigger these browsers to reload the page from the server.  Firefox desktop does apparently detect the dynamic data change and always loads a new page from the server with or with the "/home" appendage.

Comment: There are different ways to force a cache reset, but this isn't clear in your question. I thought your problem is about infinite redirection.

To clear the cache, there are specific HTTP headers that you can use, but note that they have to be used on each cached resource, not just your main page.

This is why typically people set up a cache key or version, that affects the urls of your resources (e.g. paths, subdomains or query: `x.com/%key%/images/x.png`, `%key%.assets.x.com/images/x.png` or `x.com/images/x.png?v=%key%`).

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for answering.  We don't think the problem is the server caches, but different browser's local browser caches.  Chrome, Edge, and Safari seem to have a way to test for new content before re-downloading the page.  If they don't see enough change, they just read from their local caches.  Firefox retrieves new data from the server every time.  We found if we add "/home" to the url, chrome, edge, and safari WILL go back to the server to retrieve new data...every single time.  How do we add "/home" to the url in the browser address bar without infinite redirection?

Comment: I never said server caches... the server controls the client cache through some specific headers.

I'm not sure what you are thinking, but browsers do not know when "the page sufficiently changes", especially since they won't even know since they just load the local cache.

As I said before, this is up to you(r server). You(r server) should tell the browsers how long something should be cached, from some non-cachable entrypoint (e.g. /home in your case). Then you should "break"/"bust" the cache through one of the mechanisms I already mentioned.

Comment: If you tell the browser that some images expires in 3 months, it will not load that image for three months (unless the local cache has been cleared for some reason). It will not think "hm, main page changed, so maybe image also changed".

Comment: OK, thanks Christian.
I see you are trying to help.
How do I configure the server to "tell the browsers how long something should be cached..."

Comment: I've updated my answer.